# Break a string variable's content into two parts

Tags: java, android, regex, string, variables

I have a string variable, I have to divide the content of the String variable into two parts and save them in two different string variables. I have already extracted one part of it, but I am not able to extract the other part.

This is the code:

```
String set_id="(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
set_id = set_id.substring(set_id.indexOf("(") + 1);
set_id = set_id.substring(0, set_id.indexOf(")"));
```

The above code has extracted the digit **1** for me which is saved in the **set_id** variable.

Now I want to extract **Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1** from the variable and save it in a variable named **set_name**.

**The format of the variable's content will always remain the same, but the digit and the name itself may vary.**

What should I do to extract the different parts of the string?

Comment: Using regex would be a better option to extract such values if the format is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the original string when you are getting the first substring. Save each substring in a new variable:

```
String set_id="(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
String part1 = set_id.substring(set_id.indexOf("(") + 1);
part1 = part1.substring(0, part1.indexOf(")"));
String part2 = set_id.substring(set_id.indexOf(")")+2);
```

Comment: the name is getting extracted properly, but the id looks like: (1. The opening bracket needs to be removed

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the third line to reference 'part1' instead of 'set_id'. Try it with the updated code above, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\\((\d+)\\)\s*(.+)
```

`$1` gives the id and `$2` gives name.

Here,

`\\(` and `\\)` match opening and closing brackets. (escaped, as `(` and `)` have special meaning)

`(\d+)` matches one or more digits (captured, so that $1 can be used to refer this)

`\s*` matches zero or more spaces

`(.+)` matches one or more (any) characters (again captured)

Use it like

```
String string = "(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
id = string.replaceAll("\\((\d+)\\)\s*(.+)","$1");
name = string.replaceAll("\\((\d+)\\)\s*(.+)","$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is the same:

`set_id.substring(set_id.indexOf(")")+2);`

Answer (score 0):

Check this ... a better and efficient REGEX can be used ...

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d{0,1})\\)(.*$)");
    String string = "(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Total matches: " + matcher.groupCount());
        for(int i=1, max=matcher.groupCount(); i<=max; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(i + " : " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I aaded "]" to find out out the end carachter.

```
String set_id="(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1]";
        String set_name=set_id.subSequence(set_id.indexOf(')')+1, set_id.indexOf(']')).toString();
        System.out.println(set_name);
```

Now its working for me.

O/P:--  Speed Test 150(min) Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to extract the  variables.Below is the sample code.

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+).+?(\\d+)\\(");
    String sample = "(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String originalString = "(1) Speed Test 150(min) Demo 1";
        String setId = originalString.replaceAll("\\((\\d+)\\)\\s*(.+)", "$1").trim();
        String setName = originalString.replaceAll("\\((\\d+)\\)\\s*(.+)", "$2").trim();
        System.out.println("setId: " + setId);
        System.out.println("setName: " + setName);

    }
}
```